# Connection refused - connect(2) with rake db:seed on Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, database

I am using `rails 3.2` and `mongoid`.

I make these steps for setting my database:

```
// Add an Admin User (to the admin db)
use admin
db.addUser("theadmin", "anadminpassword")

// Use your database
use superuser

// Add a user (to your database)
db.addUser("John", "passwordForJohn")

// show all users:
db.system.users.find()

// add readonly user (kinda cool)
db.addUser("readonly", "passwordForJohn", true)
```

In my `mongo.yml` I have:

```
production:
  host: localhost
  port: 27017
  username: John
  password: passwordForJohn
  database: namedatabase
```

You can see in http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication

My problem is that now I try run:

```
rake db:seed
```

I get now this error:

```
rake aborted!
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was fixed:

The problem was with solr server:

If you have solr server in your project:

1º Make sure that the Solr server is started before you seed:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
rake sunspot:reindex
```

2º Run your seed:

```
rake db:seed
```

Regards